# Elasticsearch: Wildcard search not working for text field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a text field over which I am doing wildcard search. However it is not working as expected.

Example:
Field: log_message
Value: watchdog watchdog6: watchdog did not stop!

If I use watchd* or watchdog, it matches.
However if I use log_message: "watchdog*stop" (in discover search bar in kibana), it doesn't match and I get 0 hits.
I can make it match with watchdog AND stop but I want to use the wildcard.

This is the mapping for the field:

```
   "log_message": {
     "type": "text",
     "fields": {
       "keyword": {
         "type": "keyword",
         "ignore_above": 256
       }
     }
   },
```

Any idea why the search is not working?

Comment: Wildcard syntax for single character is `?` not `_`. In addition, what query are you using. You may have to specify `analyze_wildcard` to true in case you are using `Query String`.

Comment: He's using Kibana, so he doesn't have any leverage on `analyze_wildcard`.

Comment: Yes, while finally I will be creating a query but right now I want to see the results on Kibana. And I expected this to work. It did so in the past. Wondering what changed now. Also, I am using *. The _ is only for field name which doesn't matter.

Comment: Below query doesn't work as well. POST /myindex/_search?pretty
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "log_message:watchdog*stop",
      "analyze_wildcard":true
    }
  }
}